# A word that means "of few words" or "without words"

Tags: single-word-requests

I assume that in English there is a word for everything, and I am looking for one that roughly means "of few words" or "of no words". The closest I could think of is non-verbal, but it sounds a bit too dry. Is there a better word?

Note: I did check for antonyms of "verbal" before I posted here, but didn't find any.

Comment: Could you clarify a little? Do you mean a passage with few words, or a person who uses few words, or ...? The words terse, concise, taciturn, laconic could apply.

Comment: The asker is looking for "reticent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider *laconic*, *taciturn*, and  synonyms such as *pithy* and *terse*:

• *[laconic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laconic#Adjective)*, “Using as few words as possible; pithy and concise”
• *[taciturn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taciturn#Adjective)*, “Silent; temperamentally untalkative; disinclined to speak”
• *[pithy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pithy#Adjective)*, “Concise and meaningful.”
• *[terse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terse#Adjective)*, “Abruptly or brusquely short” and “(of speech or style) Brief, concise, to the point”
• and per tchrist's comment, *[pauciloquent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pauciloquent)*, “Using few words when speaking”

Comment: And *pauciloquent*.

Answer (score 0):

[Succinct](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=succinct):

> Characterized by clear, precise expression in few words; concise and terse: *a succinct reply; a succinct style.*

(American Heritage Dictionary)

Comment: Since you ask, you could link to or include the text of a dictionary definition to support your answer.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). :)

Answer (score 0):

speechless - meaning there are no words to describe what you are feeling

Answer (score -1):

**[Brevity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brevity):**

> the quality of expressing much in few words; terseness: Brevity is the soul of wit.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: *Brevity* means expressing something with few words. It doesn't describe a person or statement. You wouldn't say "this statement is brevity", you could say "this statement is brief". That still wouldn't be quite right. This question is looking for an adjective not a noun.

Comment: @MattЭллен "A <b>word</b> that means “of few words” or “without words” & "in English there is a word for everything, and I am looking for one that roughly means "of few words" or "of no words" Please point out where the OP requests "a person or statement"

Comment: What else would be "of few words"?