# Word to describe a person who only speaks a few words

Tags: phrase-requests

I need help recalling a phrase or a word. This phrase is used to describe a person who speaks as few words as possible. He or she only speaks when others asks him or her a question.

I've seen this phrase before. It's something like *He is stingy with his words*.

Comment: *Taciturn* or *reticent* might be the words that you're not able to recollect.

Comment: "Succinct" is also a possibility, though it is rather positive in connotation, and associated to the ability to be concise when speaking, yet clear.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan "reticent" means that the person is reluctant to speak, but when they do actually speak they might speak normally.  That is, it doesn't say anything about communication **style**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A word that means "of few words" or "without words"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177943/a-word-that-means-of-few-words-or-without-words)

Comment: @sumelic the answers are better on this question, who cares which question was posted first, it's the answers that count.

Comment: @sumelicand I'll retract my suggestion and vote for migration, it's too late now.

Comment: Avoid asking for help remembering a word or phrase you’ve forgotten. This is what we call a “guessing game” question. They’re not a good fit for the site – or, to my knowledge, any SE site. See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”.

Comment: @MetaEd the OP accepted Lawrence's answer like ten hours ago, the OP recognized and knew what the phrase was  when Lawrence posted the answer, so the OP accepted. You could say the game had finished. The winner, so to speak, has been declared.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed. One can't win them all.

Comment: I know this is both answered and closed at this point, but I just wanted to add something I happened to think of just now: "He uses (his) words sparingly."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider calling him a *man of few words*.

> **of few words** *phrase*
>   Taciturn.
>   ‘he's a man of few words’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of_few_words)

Comment: @TONYLEECD You're welcome. :)

Comment: I think that "taciturn" and "laconic" (see @Peter's answer) are both good suggestions and have subtly different meanings, see https://wikidiff.com/taciturn/laconic  I personally think "laconic" is better because it describes a more permanent attribute of a person: in other words, someone might be ordinarily talkative but taciturn when questioned by the police, for example.

Answer (score 19):

You ask for "*a phrase or a word*": the obvious *word* that comes to mind is:

> **Taciturn** 
> *adjective*
>
> 1. inclined to silence; reserved in speech; reluctant to join in conversation.
> 2. dour, stern, and silent in expression and manner.
>
> [*dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taciturn)

Comment: Haha, how odd that the dictionary's definition for the phrase I suggested was also one of few words ... in fact, a single word - *taciturn*. Isn't there something against single-word definitions? :)

Comment: @Lawrence There's definitely an appropriateness to that definition... presumably it's just acting as a pointer to the full definition listed under _Taciturn_. (Although it would be ironic if that entry was: **Taciturn**: _A person of few words_ :-))

Answer (score 12):

I'd go with:

> laconic

[From Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laconic#Adjective):

> Using as few words as possible; pithy and concise.

Comment: I guess you could add, like other answers, a small explanation of why this choice of word is correct. That should add to the word count.

Comment: or a dictionary link

Comment: You should copy paste dictionary definition

Comment: I think "laconic" is better than "taciturn" because it's better suited to describing a more permanent attribute of a person:  "taciturn" might be used to describe a temporary state like a mood.

Answer (score 7):

I'd go with ***[terse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terse)***.

From dictionary.com:

> **[terse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terse)**
>
> adjective
>
> 1. neatly or effectively concise; brief and pithy, as language.
> 2. abruptly concise; curt; brusque.

With a connotation of *unpleasant* terseness, then you might want ***[curt](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/curt)*** or ***[brusque](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brusque)***, as mentioned in definition 2 above, or as someone else suggested, ***[taciturn](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taciturn)***.

If neutral, though, I would stick with ***[terse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terse)***.

Comment: Terse is better suited to describing a specific communication than it is as an attribute of a person.  In other words, you might say that a conversation was terse but you wouldn't tend to say that someone was a "terse person".

Comment: I realize personal anecdotal evidence only goes so far, but I actually suggested this answer due to a history of multiple people literally calling me "terse" for always using only what few words I felt necessary to convey my thoughts.  (I speak very differently from how I write.)  But yes, even so, if the OP is looking for a specific noun to use on its own, then my answer falls flat.

Answer (score 3):

[reticent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reticent):

adjective

1. disposed to be silent or not to speak freely; reserved.
2. reluctant or restrained.

Comment: That's a really good one, but you might want to add that there's a connotation associated with it.  It borders on negative, but isn't quite.  One may be neutrally reserved, but it's different to be reticent, more actively silent, rather than simply silent by habit.  It's like the difference between a passive silence and a hushed silence.

Answer (score 2):

[**monosyllabic**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monosyllabic) - literally meaning words of only one syllable, it is also used to describe people using brief or few words to signify reluctance to engage in conversation. It can imply rude or unfriendly.

> He grunted a monosyllabic reply

[dictionary.com]